# Where to change font color for the SQL File editor view in Zend Studio 9?

Tags: configuration, zend-studio

I want to change the colors of the sql file editor view that is active when one opens sql-files. I cannot find the settings anywhere in the preferences. Where do I have to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am personally using Zend Studio 10.1 but believe it is located in the same place.

```
Open zend studio
Click file
Click preferences
expand general
expand appearance
click on colors and fonts
expand sql editor in the main list box.
```

From here you can edit each entry to select the colors you would prefer.